# Adicionar um novo Idioma no Xamarin.Essentials: Text-to-Speech

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, xaml

Estou querendo fazer um app, que tranforme texto em vozes...

Para isso achei o [Xamarin.Essentials: Text-to-Speech](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/essentials/text-to-speech)

Consegui o que queria, mas o ponto que quero chegar é:

**Consigo alterar a voz do reprodutor?**

**Consigo adicionar um novo idioma?**

Alguem que ja trabalhou com isso, consegue me informar como?

Sera que tem algum jeito nativo de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

No método [`SpeakAsync(String, SpeechOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.texttospeech.speakasync?view=xamarin-essentials) você possui o [`SpeechOptions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.speechoptions?view=xamarin-essentials), aonde você pode setar as seguintes propriedades:

| Propriedade | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `Locale` | Obtêm ou define um idioma (depende do sistema) |
| `Pitch` | Obtêm ou seta o tom a ser usado ao falar |
| `Volume` | Obtêm ou seta volume de quando estiver falando |

Para obter os "locales" disponíveis use o método [`TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.texttospeech.getlocalesasync?view=xamarin-essentials)

O código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
var locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();
```

Dessa forma você poderá obter todos idiomas **suportados** no dispositivo atual e usando [`System.Linq`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq) você poderá "filtrar" os valores desejado, acaso não tenha o idioma de interesse poderá emitir uma mensagem de erro ou qualquer coisa que desejar, exemplo (não testado):

```
var locale = locals.FirstOrDefault(loc => string.Equals(loc.Country, "Brasil"));
```

Depois de obter o idioma basta setar no `SpeechOptions`, ficando assim:

```
var locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();

var locale = locales.FirstOrDefault(loc => string.Equals(loc.Country, "Brasil"));

var opts = new SpeechOptions()
    {
        Volume = 1.0f,
        Pitch = 1.0f,
        Locale = locale
    };

await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync("Olá mundo", opts);
```

Não é garantido que todos dispositivos vão ter os idiomas desejados, pois isso depende do sistema operacional e não do Xamarin.

Pelo que notei, dependendo do sistema podem existir algumas variações nos nomes na hora de filtrar, penso que o mais interessante seja adicionar um *combobox* que use os valores retornados de `TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync()`, assim fica a critério do usuário decidir qual idioma usar.